# How to fix Cannot read property 'next' of undefined?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

In API service I want to add the error to notification.
`processError` method is called in http request with binding : `catchError(error=>this.processError(error)),`

api.service:

```
private processError(res: HttpErrorResponse) {
    this.currentErrorSubject.next(res);
    console.log('ERROR', res)
    // this.snackBar.open(`${res.message}`, 'Hide', {duration:10000, horizontalPosition: 'right', panelClass:['error-snack']})
    let notification = new Notification(1, 'error', 'HELLO KITTY')
    this.notificationService.addNotification(notification)

    return observableThrowError(res);
  }
```

notification.service:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class NotificationService {
  isOpen : boolean
  private notifications = new Array<Notification>();
  public notificationsSubject: ReplaySubject<Notification[]>;
  constructor(
    private snackBar: MatSnackBar,
  ) { }

  open() {
    this.isOpen=true

  }

  addNotification(notification: Notification) {      

        this.notifications = [...this.notifications, notification];
        console.log('NOTIF', this.notifications)

        this.notificationsSubject.next(this.notifications);
    }
```

The error occurs in the '`addNotification`' function, where `this.notificationsSubject` is undefined. Can you explain why it is undefined? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to initialize `notificationsSubject` with a default value:

```
public notificationsSubject: ReplaySubject<Notification[]> = new ReplaySubject({ /* ... */ })
```